# Lingual shell cannot find existing tables

Tags: cascading

I followed instruction in http://docs.cascading.org/lingual/1.0/#_running_queries and set up lingual and catalog.  I also registered 2 tables and I can see them by using !tables command inside lingual shell.  But I failed to select them and the error is "table not found".  I'm sure I use correct schema name.

[image]

Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can query the table by adding "" as below:

> select * from "schemaname"."tablename";

I read the link but there's nowhere mention that I should use double quotation!